# EF code-first, how to map derived class to table (without including base class in EF model)?

Tags: c#-4.0, inheritance, ef-code-first

I have a table that holds file-folder like information {Id, FileName, Folder, ...} -> let's call it File

```
1, Presentation, Work\Presentations
2, CV, Private
3, Report, Work
```

And I need to represent this information in a treelist control.

For the above data it would be like this:

```
Work                       //Folder
|->Presentation            //Folder
    |->Presentation        //File
|->Report                  //File
Private                    //Folder
|->CV                      //File
```

For this purpouse I made some classes:

```
TreeNode
{
    ...some properties

    List<TreeNode> Descendants;
}

File : TreeNode
{
    ...
}

Folder : TreeNode
{
    ...
}
```

When I read "File" data from DbContext, I generate the Folder+File structure in a List and then add this List as a Datasource to DevExpress TreeList control

The problem is that, I need only this "File" POCO class included in my EF model, without properties that are in the base class "TreeNode"

**I tried to configure this by using fluent-api for "File"** 
-> adding Ignore(x=>x. ..) for inherited TreeNode properties - but that turns out to be not allowed
-> then i tried to find a way to mark TreeNode POCO class to be "Not mapped" - with no success

**Then I thought that maybe Table per concrete Class inheritance could be solution for this** (although I think this inheritance type is not recommended)

```
public BaseTypeMapping() //ctor in EntityTypeConfiguration<BaseTypeMapping>
{
    .Map<DerivedType>(m=>
        {
            //commented because I don't need properties from base class in my database
            // m.MapInheritedProperties(); 
            m.ToTable("DerivedTypeTable");
        }
    )
}
```

In my DbContext I define it like this:

```
public DbSet<TreeNode> Files { get; set; }
```

When I want to get all the files from DbContext, I use this:

```
var autotexts = context.Files.OfType<File>()ToList();
```

**but I get an error "Invalid object name 'dbo.TreeNodes'."** so I suppose entity framework expects this base class to be mapped to EF as well.

**Is there a way to  make this work?**